How to reverse and transpose a row?
I try using the formula in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404655/google-sheet-how-to-reverse-and-transpose-a-row
The formula works well when the range is directly referred in the formula, see below:

However, when let function is used and a function is used to create a range.    It returns error, see below:  (This is a replica of my worksheet and there is a reason that I created a range using another function.)

I have some checking and find that the error was caused by TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Range1)), would you please advise any idea of this case?
The sample sheet link is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KsxpdBz2n3Dmw_HV3vHBcJ2XP8H1-5UdlJpeyACo2MA/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks.

The linked stackoverflow post doesn't even have your formula. More importantly, I think my accepted answer there would still  work even with your stacked ranges.

TOCOL w/ SEQUENCE
Include Empty Values
=LET(
   arr,{"A", "B", IF(1,), "D", "E"},
   SORT(
     TOCOL(arr),
     SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(arr)),))

COLUMNS  IF  LET  SEQUENCE  SORT  TOCOL
Skip Empty Values
=LET(
  arr,{"A", "B", IF(1,), "D", "E"},
  SORT(
    TOCOL(arr,1),
    SEQUENCE(COUNTA(arr)),))

COUNTA  IF  LET  SEQUENCE  SORT  TOCOL
